# rails nested attributes not save to images table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm trying to save two object (image and event) using one form (event form),
but the when i submit the button there is only event object that created, the images object not save to images table,

*models/event.rb*

```
has_one :images, :class_name => '::Refinery::Image'
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
```

*models/image.rb*

```
belongs_to :events, class_name: 'Refinery::Events::Event'
```

*events_controller.rb*

```
def new
   @event = Event.new
   @event.build_images
end

def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
end

def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:nama, :deskripsi, images_attributes:[:id, :image_name, :image_size, :image_width, :image_height, :created_at, :updated_at, :image_mime_type, :image_uid, :image_title, :image_alt, :event_id] )
end
```

*events/_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for [refinery, :events, @event], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= render '/refinery/admin/error_messages',
                 :object => @event,
                 :include_object_name => true  %>

  <div class='field nama_field string_field'>
    <%= f.label :nama %>
    <%= f.text_field :nama %>
  </div>

  <div class='field deskripsi_field text_field'>
    <%= f.label :deskripsi %>
    <%= f.text_area :deskripsi, :rows => 8 %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :images do |ff| %>
    <div>
      <%= ff.label :images %>
      <%= ff.file_field :images %>
    </div>
   <% end %>

   <div class='actions'>
    <%= f.submit t('.send') %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

anyone can help me why the images not saved into images table?

Comment: What's the "permitted parameters" in rails log?

Comment: it's shown `unpermitted parameters: images`

Comment: whats the params logged in the console, and whats the permitted params?

Comment: but if i let images_attributes empety like `images_attributes: [ ]`, it's show `unpermitted parameters images_attributes` in log

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3ozxbt5wYfWj8G58junWmY5oC1To5PDPoaaB5PhFFewejb2iXM+/KfpuS9VI0C8IVTcjTP8kReMm7wPjLAahIg==", "event"=>{"nama"=>"ssssspp", "deskripsi"=>"asdasda", "periode_start(1i)"=>"2016", "periode_start(2i)"=>"6", "periode_start(3i)"=>"12", "periode_end(1i)"=>"2016", "periode_end(2i)"=>"6", "periode_end(3i)"=>"12", "lokasi"=>"", "jumlah"=>"", "gender_id"=>"", "age_id"=>"", "event_types_id"=>"", "des_acara"=>"", "key_kata"=>"", "tipe_sponsor"=>"", "dana"=>"", "exposure_ids"=>["3", ""], "enggagement_ids"=>["1", ""]

Comment: , "images_attributes"=>{"images"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f57b48834a8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160612-2620-othknm.jpg>, @original_filename="struk-10-mar-08.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"event[images_attributes][images]\"; filename=\"struk-10-mar-08.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}, "commit"=>"Send message", "locale"=>:en}

Comment: sorry for split it into 2 comments, because the text too long..